# Software Architecture - Defining an extension in a domain model

Tags: domain-model

If you had a domain model like this one: 
[image]

How would you define an extension (something that would only happen as an exception)?
Do you draw a box around it like you do in a e.g. a sequence diagram?

Comment: Forgive me, the field of programming overloads a great many terms. What exactly do you mean by "extension"?

Comment: @candied_orange
In the field of systems engineering and software architecture, an extension is only something that would happen as an exception.

Comment: you said that already and it only makes it sound like you're talking about the kind of exception you throw. Please make what you mean clear in the question itself.

Comment: @candied_orange
If for instance a ship reaches a floodgate, which a sensor detects, it would send a signal to a computer in the control tower. However, if the worker doesn't notice the signal that has been sent to the computer in the control tower, an alarm would start after for instance 5 minutes.
Normally, in the main case scenario, an alarm wouldn't start, so it is exception or in diagram and use cases it is called an extension.

Comment: Again, please edit clarifications into the question. If you wish to call my attention to the edit you can just type "@candied_orange see edit"

Comment: A domain model is a conceptual thing - the shared understanding of the modeled domain, the code being an expression of that model. A diagram like this is just a view (a diagrammatic representation) of some aspect of the model. If you need to represent a different aspect (exceptional flow), just make another diagram, or add elements to this one and annotate it somehow. How you do it *doesn't really matter* as long as you and your team and other interested collaborators understand it. These diagrams are for *you*.

Comment: BTW, an alternate/exceptional flow won't be obvious in a static structure class diagram - you may add some relevant classes, but it won't be obvious at what time they get to play their role; consider sequence diagrams instead.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical domain, the domain model can not be represented in a single diagram that is both readable and fits on one page/screen. This means that a domain model, even when showing just the static structure, will be represented by multiple diagrams that each show different aspects and different levels of detail.

With that in mind, your extension should be in a separate diagram that shows only the classes and relations that are relevant for the extension.

Comment: Apart from drawing the extension in a separate diagram, how do you define the overall extension in the main domain model?

Comment: @asd987, what do you mean by "main domain model"? Do you mean that picture of 10x2 meters where you still need a magnifying glass to read the class names?

Comment: @asd987 - I mean, just add some text (or a link) that says, "See also <the other diagram>". Don't get too formal with these diagrams, that's a waste of time, and it will lead to analysis paralysis. If you are doing things right, you are going to deviate from these diagrams later on anyway. Some you'll update, some will become obsolete and you'll throw them away. The diagrams are there to help you think and visualize things, they are not the goal in themselves.